# In Terraform can you read then write a json file

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

So I have a Terraform script that creates a Centos VM under Azure then grabs a tar file untars it and runs an installation script at the end of this script it creates a json manifest file, what I want to do is read that json script get a value then create another json file that the next installation script will use, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is not the right tool for the job specified.
There is no way to do that from the terraform.

You need to use some other provisioning tool. And even then I would suggest creating your instances one by one so you have time to populate your new json file and share it to other instances